# Print a 2D array as a grid in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, output

I'm looking to print a 2D array (of values inputted by the user) as a grid.

This is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(){

       int rowSize = 4;
       int colSize = 4;
       int disp[rowSize][colSize];

       int i, j;
       for(i=0; i<rowSize; i++) {
          for(j=0;j<colSize;j++) {
             printf("Enter value for disp[%d][%d]:", i, j);
             scanf("%d", &disp[i][j]);
          }
      }

       printf("Two Dimensional array elements:\n");
       for(i=0; i<rowSize; i++) {
         for(j=0; j<colSize; j++) {
            printf("%d ", disp[i][j]);
             }
          }

       return 0;
       }
```

Which outputs the array as one line of numbers. How do I insert a new line after the end of each row?

Thank you

Comment: As you say yourself, you need to insert (print) a newline after the end of each row. Now think a little bit about how you print each row... Just simple experimentation would probably have solved it for you quicker than it took to write this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a newline to your print loop, see below:

```
   printf("Two Dimensional array elements:\n");
   for(i=0; i<rowSize; i++) {
     for(j=0; j<colSize; j++) {
        printf("%d ", disp[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");  // <<<<<< added newline
      }
```

Example printout from running the code:

```
Two Dimensional array elements:
0 1 2 3 
4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 11 
12 13 14 15
```

Even better if you add some alignment with tabs - simply use `printf("%d\t", disp[i][j]);`, result:

```
Two Dimensional array elements:
0   1   2   3   
4   5   6   7   
8   9   10  11  
12  13  14  15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(i=0; i<rowSize; i++) {
     for(j=0; j<colSize; j++) {
        printf("%d ", disp[i][j]);
         }
       printf("\n");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is the same as the two other answers but I would advocate for renaming the variables to something like:
numberOfRows and numberOfColumns
     This way it is easier to understand logically where the new line should go. ie) after we finish with 1 row of columns. Being explicit while you are learning will help you figure out the logic easier.

```
for(i=0; i<numberOfRows; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<numberOfColumns; j++) {
        printf("%d ", disp[i][j]);
     }
     printf("\n");
}
```